# Why doesn't kill -s<number> work anymore?

Tags: shell, zsh, kill

For the longest time, I would run `kill -s9` to send `SIGKILL` to the process, now it seems it doesn't work on Debian Testing,

```
$ kill -s 9 988224
kill: unknown signal: SIG9
kill: type kill -l for a list of signals
```

Moreover, it seems as if it's still documented to work,

```
-<signal>
-s <signal>
--signal <signal>
      Specify the signal to be sent.  The  signal  can  be
      specified  by using name or number.  The behavior of
      signals is explained in signal(7) manual page.
```

Interesting, `kill -9` works. Why did the `-s9` usage stop working?

Comment: You are probably seeing the behaviour of your shell's builtin `kill` (specifically `zsh` by the looks of it)

Comment: @steeldriver exactly what was happening

Comment: See [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/kill.html) to which zsh's kill conforms here. Use `kill -s KILL` to send SIGKILL, `kill -s 9` is not POSIX. `kill -9` and `kill -KILL` are only POSIX+XSI, so not portable either (though `zsh` supports both). Avoid signal numbers, prefer signal names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` has it's own version `kill`,

```
$ /bin/kill -s9 998126

$ kill -s9 998126
kill: unknown signal: SIGS9
kill: type kill -l for a list of signals
```

It's not compatible with `/bin/kill` from `procps-ng`. The `zsh` builtin offers,

```
   kill [ -s signal_name | -n signal_number | -sig ] job ...
   kill -l [ sig ... ]
```

With  `kill -n 9` as the closest analog. For more information see [`man zshbuiltins`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshbuiltins).

Comment: All POSIX shells have `kill` builtin since they need to support job specs like `kill %1`, jobs being internal to the shell, it's not limited to `zsh`. The `kill` man page would document the standalone `kill` utility. For the documentation of `zsh`'s `kill`, you'd rather use `info zsh kill`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas if I was taking a test I would have gotten that right and provided the same answer. Yet, a decade of using bash, and my brain hasn't quite wrapped around the notion of "not everything will be the same." I changed for PowerLevel9k, and besides the nifty prompt and faster start time everything really feels like the same boring shell.